# UIDs for service users in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-accounts, services

Some third-party servers should be run under a special user for security reasons (eg, PostgreSQL is typically run by "postgres"). Of course, these service users should not show up in the Mac OS X login windows. I know how to create hidden users using `dscl` or `dsimport`, but I'm wondering what the best policy is for assigning UIDs (and matching GIDs). Apple's [documentation](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf) states that UIDs from 0 to 100 are reserved (pg. 69), but OS X comes with several special users and groups outside that range. I used to use ids from 401 onwards for services, but I noticed that OS X 10.6 has started using that range for groups created by the Sharing pane in System Preferences.

What is the recommended ID range to use for third-party services, then? Perhaps I should just use IDs in the 500 range, since all that is needed to hide a user in Snow Leopard is setting his password to "*"?

Also, most of Apple's services have names starting with an underscore, with an alias sans underscore; eg, `_sandbox` and `sandbox`. Is there any special significance to this? Should I do the same for my services?

**Edit**: although I said "or `dsimport`", one should really use `dscl` to create hidden users. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/70156/hide-users-from-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-logon-screen/227420#227420) for details!

Answer (score 2):

Amusingly, I found this while trying to sort out some [weird behavior we've been getting reports of during Big Sur updates](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/4531), and then a few days later stumbled on a very recent, vaguely-canonical answer!

In Big Sur, the usage information for the `sysadminctl` command is updated with a new asterisk, and some new options for the -addUser action. I'll quote the relevant parts (with new options bolded), but here's [the only public copy I could find](https://github.com/kendfinger/MacHack/blob/469b6b87164084fac322d957c53e99bd8b2635ad/README.md#sysadminctl) of the full usage.

> -addUser <user name> [-fullName <full name>] [-UID <user ID>] **[-GID <group ID>]** [-shell <path to shell>] [-password <user password>] [-hint <user hint>] [-home <full path to home>] [-admin] **[-roleAccount]** [-picture <full path to user image>] (interactive] || -adminUser <administrator user name> -adminPassword <administrator password>)
>
> *Role accounts require name starting with _ and UID in 200-400 range.

If you try to use the -roleAccount option, it will indeed make you use a username with an underscore, and a UID in the 200-400 range.

Comment: Related: I'm a bit disappointed they bothered making a new option for this but still force us to jump through hoops. They know the rules and the UID range--why not pretend it's 2020 and give us an available UID in the range if we don't specify one? Or, perhaps, something like https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser=