# Make the "Other" Account viewable again and unhide my account

Tags: macos, mac, login, users

I was looking at [Hide users from Mac OS X Snow Leopard logon screen](https://superuser.com/questions/70156/hide-users-from-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-logon-screen), and used the hide users if their user id is <500 in terminal, and then proceeded to hide the "Others".

When I want to use the account, how to I unhide the others?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the opposite command, if I'm interpreting your question correctly:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool TRUE
```