# Add a Network User to Mac OS X Login screen

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, login-screen, managed

It's easy enough to [hide a user on the Mac OS X Login screen](https://superuser.com/questions/70156/hide-users-from-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-logon-screen) but, how do you **add** a network user to the Login screen?

Currently users click "Other…" and type their username & password. Most of our Macs, though managed, are primarily used by one individual. I'd like to put that individual's account name on the login screen. Anyone else who wants to login would still have to click "Other…".

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3229197?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

A far as I'm aware there is no way to add a network user to the login screen. You could make the network account mobile and then it would persist but I'm not sure if that's what you want to do without the context.

Comment: This would allow someone else to log in, and then would show their user icon the next time the log in screen comes around.

Sounds like it answers the question to me!